# C++ nested loop shape

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops

I have been making my own C++ program using nested loops to create some sort of shape. My recent project was creating a shape that looks like this

```
*
**
***
****
*****
   *****
    ****
     ***
      **
       *
```

but I have written a program which gives me a result of this

```
*
**
***
****
*****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

also here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main(){
//displays a top triangle going from 1 - 5(*)
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
        cout << "*";

    }

    cout << endl;
}
//displays a bottom to top triangle 5 - 1(*)
for (int k = 0; k <= 5; k++){
    for (int l = 5; l >= k; l--){
        cout  << "*";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
system("pause");
}
```

it would be helpful thank you :)

Comment: I would suggest either: Running your program in a debugger and watch what happens each time through each loop until you notice the incorrect output happening and/or Running your program using "pencil and paper", again noticing when the output starts looking wrong, and at that point note what the loop is doing, and why it's wrong.

Comment: I think it's funny that you suggest that someone who can't figure out how to make this program work just load up `gdb` and get hacking.

Answer (score 1):

In your second nested loop, you don't print spaces.

Have a string that is a three spaces, then after each run of the inner loop, append to it another space and print it:

```
spc = "   ";
for (int k = 0; k <= 5; k++){
    cout << spc;
    for (int l = 5; l >= k; l--){
        cout  << "*";
    }
    spc += " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Also can you please tell me what does the code you added do to this program and where was my mistake.

Comment: Man, it's pretty self-documenting.  Also you need a type before `spc`, probably `std::string`.

Comment: @Andrey That's won't be hard for OP, I wasn't writing a full solution. You'll need `main` as well :)

Comment: @user3126681 Your mistake was that you didn't print any spaces, debug your code to better understand the flow.

Answer (score 1):

In your second loop, you want:

```
std::string spc = "   "; // add #include <string> at the top of the file
for (int k = 0; k <= 5; k++) {
    cout << spc;
    for (int l = 5; l >= k; l--){
        cout << "*";
    }
    spc += " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this: http://ideone.com/hdxPQ7

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        for (j=0; j<i+1; j++){
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        for (j=0; j<i+1; j++){
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (k=5; k>i+1; k--){
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is it's output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps(Needs to be optimized).

```
 void printChars(int astrks, int spcs, bool bAstrkFirst)
 {
    if(bAstrkFirst)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<astrks;j++)
        {
            std::cout<<"*";
        }
        for(int k = 0; k<spcs;k++)
        {
            std::cout<<" ";
        }
    }
    else
    {

        for(int k = 0; k<spcs;k++)
        {
            std::cout<<" ";
        }
        for(int j = 0; j<astrks;j++)
        {
            std::cout<<"*";
        }
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int astrk = 1, spc = 7;
    for(int x = 0; x<5; x++)
    {
        printChars(astrk++, spc--, true);
    }
    for(int x = 0; x<5; x++)
    {
        printChars(--astrk, ++spc, false);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
   *****
    ****
     ***
      **
       *
```